# How to get vue-js-toggle-button change value

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I tried to get change status with Vue-js-toggle-button package:

```
<toggle-button
  @change="onToggleChange(slider.id)"
  :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
  :width="70"
  :sync="true"
  :value="Boolean(slider.status)"/>
```

And I used a method to pass current `slider.id`:

```
 onToggleChange(id) {
     let value = event.target.value;
     console.log(value);
 },
```

I tried to get `event` with `value` but it's not working correctly.

I want to get both toggle button table row `slider` id and toggle button `value` using vue js. Any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the event as argument (notice the addition of `$event`):

```html
<toggle-button
  @change="onToggleChange(slider.id, $event)"
```

And use it like:

```
onToggleChange(id, event) {                // added event as second arg
  let value = event.value;                 // changed from event.target.value to event.value
  console.log(value);
},
```

Notice that [`event` does not have `target`](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-toggle-button#events).

Demo:

```js
Vue.use(window['vue-js-toggle-button'].default)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    slider: {
      status: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onToggleChange(id, event) { // added event as second arg
      let value = event.value;  // changed from event.target.value to event.value
      console.log(value);
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-js-toggle-button"></script>

<div id="app">
  <toggle-button
    @change="onToggleChange(slider.id, $event)"
    :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
    :width="70"
    :sync="true"
    :value="Boolean(slider.status)"/>
</div>
```